# Paxos Consensus

Tags: computer-networks, consensus

how does Paxos Consensus algorithm behave in an **asynchronous environment**? Because as far as I know Paxos only work in synchronous environment. Correct me if I am wrong :)

Sorry for the noob question, started learning about Paxos yesterday only.

Answer (score 2):

The basic Paxos protocol (that is, without leader election) is totally asynchronous. In Lamport's paper, the basic protocol is derived from a consistency lemma [in section 2.2](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/lamport-paxos.pdf).

However, it does not guarantee progress (section 2):

> A restricted version of the preliminary protocol provided the
>   basic protocol that guaranteed consistency, but not progress.

(While not *guaranteeing* progress, the basic protocol never *deadlocks*. Progress is always *possible* but cannot be guaranteed in any finite amount of time)

In fact, the FLP Impossibility Result tells us that *no* asynchronous protocol can guarantee progress and be correct in the presence of failures.

Paxos adds a limited amount of dependence on time to choose *presidents*. If there is exactly one president that can communicate with enough nodes for enough time to complete the protocol, then progress is guaranteed.

However, having multiple presidents does *not* lead to inconsistency--it simply means that progress is not guaranteed.

> However, in the
>   Paxon Synod, having multiple presidents could only impede progress; it could not
>   cause inconsistency. For the complete protocol to satisfy the progress condition, the
>   method for choosing the president needed only to satisfy the following presidential
>   selection requirement (section 2.4):
>
> If no one entered or left the Chamber, then after T minutes exactly one
>   priest in the Chamber would consider himself to be the president.